# Displaying Date on a Button (Android)

Tags: android, date, button, time

I'm working on a programming exercise in which I have a single button that displays the current date. In this program I am required to make use of the OnClickListener for the activity; Use the Java Date class to get the current time and date and use the Button's setText() method to display that date as the Button's caption.

I created the following button in the .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="edu.arizona.uas.fonji.hellodate.HelloDate" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_button"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="3000dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I created the following  code in the .java file. I don't what i'm doing wrong:

```
package edu.arizona.uas.fonji.hellodate;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Date;


public class HelloDate extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button dateButton;
    Date date = new Date();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_date);

        dateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date_button);
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dateButton.setText(date.toString());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hello_date, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: android:layout_width="400dp" android:layout_height="3000dp" are you sure that shouldn't just be fill_parent and fill_parent?

Comment: In which format do you want the date to appear?

Comment: The code is working good. What is your problem? Can you please paste you logcat.

Comment: Hello @Nava2011 thanks for the feedback. I'm new to all this. When I ran the emulator, I did not realize I will have to click on the button first for the date to appear. I expected it appear without an initial click on the button. So yes, you're right the code is working. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: @joao2fast4u the format of the date doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: @Zhuinden I didn't know about fill_parent for making the view as big as the parent but I did use it and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, there's fill_parent, wrap_content and match_parent. I'm not entirely sure what the difference is between fill and match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to the code:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); //set to current time
            dateButton.setText(date.toString());
        }
```

If you want to change the format, then you should use the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
dateButton.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Hello @zhuinden thank you very much for the help. It was very useful and indeed it helped solve the problem. Instead of adding the code I had to replace code I had written with what you offered. Thank you again. –  user3839913 16 mins ago